# how to update price when user check radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all, I would like to apologize if this sounds ridiculous. I have this HTML where it displays the house info that I retrieve from the database. So, I would like to update the price. For example, a price to book a house is 150(fixed). If he/she wants additional facilities such as air conditioner(20) the total will be 170. So, {house.price} will be 170. What I'm trying to do is, If the user wants to update the info, which he/she wants to change to Wifi(10), the {house.price} will automatically change to 160 or vice versa.

The jquery below I used to calculate the house's price when I first insert the information about the house. So, I don't if I can use to update the price.  is there's another way of doing it?

**HTML**

```
 <form id=my-form>

<select id="type" name="type" class="form-control">
<option id="1" data-price='150' value="House" <c:if test="${house.type=='House'}">selected</c:if>></option>
</select>


<label  for="facilities">Facilities</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="description" data-price="20" value="Aircond" <c:if test="${house.description =='Aircond'}">checked</c:if>>Aircond<br>
<input type="radio" name="description" data-price="10" value="Wifi" <c:if test="${house.description =='Wifi'}">checked</c:if>>Wifi<br>


<label for="price">Price/Night</label>
<input type="text" id='my-total' class="form-control" name="price" value="<c:out value="${house.price}" />" >
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#my-form').on('change', function(){
  update_total();
});

function update_total(){
  var tot = 0;
  var price = 0;
  $('#my-form input:checked').each(function(){
    price = $(this).data('price');
    if(price > 0){
      tot += price;
    }
  });
  $('#my-form select').each(function(){
    price = $("option:selected", this).data('price');
    if(price > 0){
      tot += price;
    }
  });
  $('#my-total').val(tot);
}
update_total();
});

credit to( I can't remember who for giving this code)
```

Comment: AJAX, ajax will run active on your website, so it can live update your price.

Comment: Above jquery code works fine in calculating price (just remove `});` from end above), then how you want this?